# How do I sign the final .apk file with Android++?

Tags: android, apk, sign

I'm using Android++ to develop Android apps.

Does anybody know how to sign the final release version APK? I tried to find options to sign my APK on the project settings, but there are no such options available; I am not familiar with Eclipse.

Comment: You can do it manually if you have to: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

Comment: Thank you, I've found how to sign the final apk automatically with Android++ : simply add *.apk to the project, then modify the .vcxproj, set the apk's rule to 'AndroidApkSign', reopen the project, there will be settings show up inside the project settings, remove the apk after you've done with signing settings (VS will remember it). this is actually the same as manually signing process.

Comment: Hey, if you figured it out. Please post  your own answer and mark it as "correct" so the next person can read and learn as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for VS 2013 and Android++ 0.4.0 one can do the following:
- Go to Property Manager and add a new property sheet for required configuration.
- In the new property sheet go to the Android Apk Signing tool - Jarsigner and specify keystore, keystore password,...